# Incorrect redirection after commenting on custom type

Tags: comments, redirect

I use custom  post type, and when users make a comment on page
`www.mysite.com/custom-type/2013/01/20/post-name/`
they are redirected to
`www.mysite.com/2013/01/20/post-name/#comment-2231` [e.g. without `/custom-type/`]. So they get `404`.
In all other pages and posts (that is not custom type), the redirecting after commenting works well.
What is the problem?

Comment: Does this happen if you use a default theme?

Comment: @s_ha_dum I dont know, and I can not try it, because the site must be working all the time with the current theme...

Comment: Don't you have a development install? Highly recommended especially since this site is so critical you can't take it down for three minutes it would take to swap themes and test this. Sorry, but this is going to be very difficult if you can't debug. If the comment form is the only place this happens, I expect that your theme has an comment form that isn't cooperative but it is hard to say. Could be a plugin too. Again, hard to say.

Comment: @s_ha_dum. Thank you. I have found what was the problem: In custom post registration, I used slug in russian `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'темы' ),`. And it seems, that it is nod good for wordpress. Now I changed it to english, and it works. May be it's a bug...